# Matching mail and pass in mongodb node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

So, I'm new to all this and was developing a login and registration page. I can easily save the data to the database while registering through registration page, but the problem is I don't know what to do during login page. What type of statements do I have to use to match the entered email address with the email addresses of each document in the "employee" collection, and then check if the password is correctly entered.

Here is my express file main.js:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var connection = require("../connection");

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render("login.html");
    });

    app.get('/adduser', function(req, res){
        res.render("login.html");
        var name = req.param('name');
        var email = req.param('email');
        var employeeid = req.param('employeeid');
        var password = req.param('password');
        var position='';
        var joining_date= '';
        var active= 'Y';

        console.log("Name: " + name + " Email: " + email + "Employee id: " +employeeid);

        connection.add(name,email,employeeid,password,position,joining_date,active);
    });

    //CHECKING IF MAIL AND PASSWORD MATCHES
    app.get('/checkuser', function(req, res){
        var email = req.param('email');
        var password = req.param('password');

        console.log(" Email: " + email);
        connection.check(email,password);
    });
```

And this is the connection file, connection.js:

```
var add=function(uname,uemail,uemployeeid,upassword,uposition,ujoining_date,uactive) {
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/HippoFeedo';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Connection established to', url);

            // Get the documents collection
            var collection = db.collection('employees');

            //Create some users
            var data = {name:uname,email:uemail,employeeid:uemployeeid,password:upassword,position:uposition,joining_date:ujoining_date,active:uactive };

            /* var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
            var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin', 'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};*/

            // Insert some users
            collection.insert(data, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "employees" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
} //NOW CHECKING IF ENTERED EMAIL AND PASS MATCHES OR EMAIL EXISTS???
var check= function(uemail,upassword)
{
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/HippoFeedo';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Connection established to', url);

            var collection = db.collection('employees');

            collection.findOne({uemail:uemail}, function(err,doc){ //I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO HERE??
                if(err) throw err;
                if(doc)
                    console.log("Found: "+uemail+", pass=");
                else
                    console.log("Not found: "+uemail);
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports.add=add;
module.exports.check=check;
```

EDITED: THE FIX FOR THE ABOVE PROBLEM IS PROVIDED BY GMANIC BELOW..

Comment: have you looked at using a framework to help with this like mongoose for your mongodb connector and express for the frontend or restify if you are running this as an api? here is an example: https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo

Comment: Sir, I've to do all this without using mongoose. Please suggest some easy queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix, you are trying to match on `uemail` but you saved it as `email`. You could even take it a step further and match on the password at the same time.

```
exports.check = function(uemail, upassword)
{
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/HippoFeedo';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Connection established to', url);

            var collection = db.collection('employees');

            collection.findOne({ email: uemail, password: upassword }, function(err, doc){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(doc) {
                    console.log("Found: " + uemail + ", pass=" + upassword);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not found: " + uemail);
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

There are some best practices that you should add in, but to answer your question this should work.

Comment: Thanks! This one was pretty straight-forward perfect answer. Thanks again.